# webpack run build but not exit command

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Webpack successfully run build, but can't auto exit command after. How to exit?

remove --progress and webpack-dashboard,still can't

webpack.base.conf.js

```
...// require
module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: util.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...util.eslint,
      ...util.cssLoaders,
      // more loaders
  },
  plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/index.html'),
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        },
      }),
    new DllLinkPlugin({
      htmlMode: true,
      config: require('./webpack.dll.conf.js'),
    }),
  ],
  stats: {
    children: false, 
    builtAt: true, 
    cached: true,
    cachedAssets: true
  }
};
```

webpack.prod.conf.js

```
// requere...
const config = require('./webpack.base.conf');
const env = require('../env.production')

module.exports = merge(config, {
  bail: true,
watch:false,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    // ... mini css html
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp('\\.(' + productionGzipExtensions.join('|') + ')$'),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    ... options
  }
});
```

package.json

```
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js",
```

link run this

```
npm run build
```

i expect exit command after Successfully build ，[not like this image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28922129/57430670-ff791e80-7262-11e9-9dde-242475dc461c.png)

Comment: Did you found any clue on this ?

Answer (score 18):

add this to your webpack.base.conf.js

```
plugins: [
    // your plugins...
    {
       apply: (compiler) => {
         compiler.hooks.done.tap('DonePlugin', (stats) => {
           console.log('Compile is done !')
           setTimeout(() => {
             process.exit(0)
           })
         });
       }
    }
]
```

This use webpack's compiler hooks,
https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#done

Comment: Can you explain the reason here?

Comment: I confirm it works! Thanks!

Comment: Man thanks a million times. Even tho this feels like hack , it helped me immensely.

Comment: Listen to me, thank you, because you have warmed the four seasons

Answer (score -1):

In my case , I set a node process to show  **webpack Bundle Analyzer** , that is why my command does not exit (a node service is always running unless I shut it down  manually)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).